# Setting top padding for a RecyclerView programatically does not work?

Tags: android, android-layout, padding

I have RecyclerView which shows some items as list on screen. Layout is as below :

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_layout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv1"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In above layout `tv1` & `tv2` have some information to show, it may be single line or multi-line, hence giving them a fix height is not possible hence along with their parent -> `top_view` both `tv1` and `tv2` are having height as wrap content.

I want top padding of `top_view` s height. That I am doing programmatically as follows :

```
top_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.top_view );
list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setPadding(list.getPaddingLeft(),
                top_view.getHeight(),
                list.getPaddingRight(),
                list.getPaddingBottom());
```

But above code has no effect, if I give hard-coded top-padding to RecyclerView as `android:paddingTop="100dp"` it works but I can't give hard-coded value, as it is dependent on `top_view`.

One more thing placing `list` below `top_view` does not work for me as I have some other requirement about this padding.

So why is this programmatically set topPadding doesn't work ?

Comment: Did you just try debugging it? All of those views heights are probably `0` because they have not been laid out yet. The ugly hack is to use `ViewTreeObserver` to wait for the layout, or you can choose to create a custom layout.

Comment: i agree with David, `top_view.getHeight()` returns 0

Comment: can you show how the design looks at your result?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak and pskink you are right top_view.getHeight() returns zero shows in debugger

Answer (score 2):

The way you manipulate views in a `RecyclerView` (besides the adapter) is through `ItemDecoration`.

Since you want to add a `topPadding` to your list it should only affect the first item, so create your custom `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` like this:

```
public class PaddingTopItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int size;

    public PaddingTopItemDecoration(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            outRect.top += size;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just add it to your  `RecylerView`:

```
// Insert your own top padding value
list.addItemDecoration(new PaddingTopItemDecoration(value));
```

Comment: Be aware of you might need to do `removeItemDecoration(ItemDecoration's object you added)` before `addItemDecoration(ItemDecoration object)` to prevent the size keep increasing due to duplicated decorators, depends on where you put your code.

Answer (score 0):

top_view.getHeight() will result to 0. the view is not yet drawn.

you can try this code. the height will be set at this point.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        // the height will be set at this point

        list.setPadding(list.getPaddingLeft(),
            top_view.getHeight(),
            list.getPaddingRight(),
            list.getPaddingBottom());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, use

```
top_view.getMeasuredHeight()
```

instead of

```
top_view.getHeight().
```

In this case, use a ViewTreeObserver. It waits for you layout to be drawn, so that your heights don't return 0 (as it would before your layout was drawn).

```
parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);

ViewTreeObserver vto = parent.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (vto.isAlive()) {
            vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    //Perform your actions here
                    list.setPadding(list.getPaddingLeft(),
                    top_view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                    list.getPaddingRight(),
                    list.getPaddingBottom());

                    //Remove observer after use
                    parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For my project I used the class that exist here

https://gist.github.com/hrules6872/b68bf3762e4d1243e480#file-spaceitemdecoration-java

it is a very simple class which will enable you to define :

-top padding

-bottom padding

-padding between elements

it can be used like this

```
//if you want padding between elements 
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(5));

//if you want padding between elements + top and bottom padding 
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpaceItemDecoration(5,true,true));
```

Kindly bare in mind that the 5 in the example is pixels, if you want DP instead you can use this method to change it from DP to pixel (it is one of many methods i have in a util class)

```
private static float cachedDpToPixelRatio = -1;

    public static float dpToPixels(Context context, int valueInDp) {
        if (cachedDpToPixelRatio == -1) {
            cachedDpToPixelRatio = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        }

        return cachedDpToPixelRatio * valueInDp;

    }
```